# Where is the error in this partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions

$$\frac{1}{(2)(u)(\sqrt{u}-1)}$$
$$\frac{1}{(2)(u)(\sqrt{u}-1)} = \frac{A}{2} + \frac{B}{u} + \frac{C}{\sqrt{u}-1}$$
$$1 = Au\sqrt{u} - Au + 2B\sqrt{u}-2B+2Cu$$
$$1 = u\sqrt{u}(A)+u(-A-2C)+\sqrt{u}(B)-2B$$
$-2B = 1\Rightarrow B=-\frac{1}{2}$  since this is the only constant value on the right side and so must equal one.
$A = 0$ since there is no term on the left side with u with the exponent $\frac{3}{2}$ ($u\sqrt{u} = u^\frac{3}{2}$).
Thus, $-A-2C=0$ (no term with u in it) $\Rightarrow 0-2C=0 \Rightarrow C=0$.
Now we get:
$$\frac{1}{(2)(u)(\sqrt{u}-1)} = \frac{0}{2} + \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{u} + \frac{0}{\sqrt{u}-1}$$
$$\frac{1}{(2)(u)(\sqrt{u}-1)} = -\frac{1}{2u}$$
What went wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it would work to begin with? It's not a rational function (although it would be if you let $x=\sqrt{u}$), and you're not following the rules for how to set up the decomposition (a term $A/2$?!?). By the way, not only do you get $B=-1/2$, you also get $B=0$ by comparing coefficients of $\sqrt{u}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have ${B\sqrt{u}+C\over u}$ instead of ${B\over u}$ in second line. You would notice this quicker if you wrote $x=\sqrt{u}$.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: If you want to decompose ${p(x)\over q(x)r(x)} = {a(x)\over q(x)} +{b(x)\over r(x)}$ then $a(x)$ must be at most one degree smaller than $q(x)$.